# Laravel Eloquent return distinct values from related model

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to return distinct values from a models relations:

I currently have three models:

**Post**

**Comment**

**Rating**

and I want to display

> This comment has the following ratings Gold,Bronze,Platinum

Each comment can have many ratings so there could be 10 Golds for each post and I am trying to avoid seeing Gold 10 times

so far I have

```
@foreach ($post->comments as $comment)
  @foreach ($comment->rating as $rating)
      <dd class="text-gray-900">{{ $rating->name }}</dd>
  @endforeach
 @endforeach
```

however this returns

**Gold  Gold  Bronze Platinum**

what I want is to see only each rating once

**Gold Bronze Platinum**

I have tried not adding foreach and instead echoing out

```
{{ $post->comments->rating->distinct() }}
```

but this returns the following error

**`Property [ratings] does not exist`**

and so if I echo just

```
{{ $post->comments }}
```

I can see the ratings_id so I know that what I need is avaible I just do not know how to access it

`[{"id":1,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null,"comment":"test post","pivot":{"post_id":11,"comment_id":1},"ratings":[{"id":1,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null,"name":"rating gold","pivot":{"comment_id":1,"rating_id":1}},{"id":2,"created_at":null,"updated_at":null,"name":"rating silver","pivot":{"comment_id":1,"rating_id":2}}`]},

I'm not very clear on how to access this data outside of a foreach loop

Comment: Can you share the table structures of those models.

Answer (score 1):

`$comment->rating` will give a collection, and I don't know any `distinct` method on the laravel collection.

You can use `$comment->rating()` that return query builder, so you can find query using that.

example `$comment->rating()->select('name')->groupBy('name')->get()`, it's will return list of unique rating based by name:

```
  @foreach ($comment->rating()->select('name')->groupBy('name')->get() as $rating)
      <dd class="text-gray-900">{{ $rating->name }}</dd>
  @endforeach
```

You can also use [unique()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-unique) method from laravel collection try:

```
$comment->rating->unique('name')
```

Comment: your suggestion for use of query builder very nearly achieves what I am looking for in that it will return a unique rating for each comment, ideally what I want is unique values across all comments rather than each comment

Comment: I think you need to give an example output that you want.  from my understanding of your question, my answer can do it.